# Cuando se vuelve a cargar la pagina el id que viene de props se borra en Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel vue el problema que encontré es que al recargar manualmente se borra el componente al igual cuando edito se borra el id que viene de props

en esta imagen es cuando agrego una facturacion carga normal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta imagen es después de recargar manualmente o al presionar F5
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como hago que el id se encripte y no se muestre en la url
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta parte también cuando actualizo manualmente se borra el componente

este es una de mis rutas en routes.js

```js
{
            path:'/cliente/editar/edit/:id',
            name:'cliente.editar.edit.gerente',
            component:require('./components/modulos/registar/clientes/editar').default,
            props:true,
            beforeEnter: (to,from,next) =>{
                verificarAcceso(to,from,next)
            }
        },
```

archivo web.php

```html
Route::get('/{optional?}', function () {
            return view('welcome');
        })->name('basepath')
            ->where('optional','.*');
```

Comment: para que no se borre deberias usar un store, como ser vuex

Comment: puedes mostrar mas un tutorial como hacerlo o un ejemplo como implementarlo gracias

Comment: primero usa vuex y aplica mi respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564071/how-do-i-break-up-my-vuex-file/63946235#63946235